# Python session.get response uses "latin-1" instead of "utf-8" encoding

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

recently while trying to use a GET request from python requests lib i have encountered a weird error.
Code:

```
response = session.get(url)
print(response.text)
```

Error:

```
  File "c:/Users/Ripe Boi/Desktop/Programavimas/Python_learning/eduka_hax/scrapper.py", line 50, in scrapeEduka
    response = session.get(url)
  File "C:\Users\Ripe Boi\Desktop\Programavimas\Python_learning\!!Envs\eduka\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 555, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ripe Boi\Desktop\Programavimas\Python_learning\!!Envs\eduka\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ripe Boi\Desktop\Programavimas\Python_learning\!!Envs\eduka\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
  File "C:\Users\Ripe Boi\Desktop\Programavimas\Python_learning\!!Envs\eduka\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\Ripe Boi\Desktop\Programavimas\Python_learning\!!Envs\eduka\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 706, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "C:\Users\Ripe Boi\Desktop\Programavimas\Python_learning\!!Envs\eduka\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 394, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Users\Ripe Boi\Desktop\Programavimas\Python_learning\!!Envs\eduka\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 234, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "c:\users\ripe boi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "c:\users\ripe boi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1270, in _send_request
    self.putheader(hdr, value)
  File "C:\Users\Ripe Boi\Desktop\Programavimas\Python_learning\!!Envs\eduka\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 219, in putheader
    _HTTPConnection.putheader(self, header, *values)
  File "c:\users\ripe boi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1202, in putheader
    values[i] = one_value.encode('latin-1')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u0173' in position 508: ordinal not in range(256)
```

What is weird to is that the error comes not from trying to print response.text attribute, but from creating response object itself.

I managed to find a hacky solution by going into python source files "lib/http/client.py" and there changing line 1202 which was the line that was throwing the error:

```
values[i] = one_value.encode('latin-1')
```

to

```
values[i] = one_value.encode('utf-8')
```

After changing these lines the response object is created successfully and there are no more further errors, but I believe that this is a bad solution, and that there has to be something better than changing python source files to force utf-8 encoding.

Thanks for any responses.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself, some of the cookies values that I transferred to `requests.session` using `session.cookies.set(cookie['name'], cookie['value'])` object were badly encoded, after not using those cookies anymore the problem is gone.